# Javascript Snake Movement and Growth

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Alright, so I've been working on making a decent snake game in javascript for awhile now, and I've gotten the basics in, but I am to the hard part in my opinion, which is how to make the snake grow, and how to fix the movement. I have a placeholder way of moving right now, but it doesn't work that well, it just moves me forward 20px in whichever direction once, not anymore than once. I want to fix that. I also want to make it so that my snake grows whenever it eats a green pellet. I have tried to find resources for this, but from what I can see none of them relate to the way I made the snake game, as lots of the ones I have seen use switch cases, which are probably more efficient than what I am doing, but are not what I am doing right now. I also need to implement game over and stuff like that, but I think I can figure that stuff out for myself. Here is the code (The main part I need help with is the movementInterval, but I put all the code I have so far so if there is any part anybody needs to see to help they can see it.):

```
var c = document.getElementById("snakeCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var score = 0;
//Snake Variables
var snakeColor = 'red';
var snakeX = 20;
var snakeY = 20;
var snakeWid = 20; 
var snakeHei = 20; 
var snakeSpeed = 500; //milliseconds
//Food Variables
var foodColor = 'green'
var foodX = 10;
var foodY = 10;
var foodWid = 20;
var foodHei = 20;
//Initial score
ctx.font = "30px Arial";
ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
ctx.fillText('Score: ' + score, 10, 340);
//Draws borders around score
function drawBorder(){
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(0, 305);
  ctx.lineTo(c.width, 305);
  ctx.stroke();
}
drawBorder();
//Draw Rectangle function       
function drawSnake(snakeX,snakeY,snakeWid,snakeHei) {
    ctx.fillStyle = snakeColor; 
    ctx.fillRect(snakeX, snakeY, snakeWid, snakeHei);
}

function drawFood(snakeX,snakeY,snakeWid,snakeHei){
        ctx.fillStyle = foodColor;
    ctx.fillRect(snakeX,snakeY,snakeWid,snakeHei)
}

 //Drawing snake on initial load
drawSnake(snakeX,snakeY,snakeWid,snakeHei);

//Drawing Food on initial load
food();
var fx, fy, fow, foh;
function food(){
  fx = c.width / foodWid;
  fow =  Math.floor(Math.random() * fx);
  foodX = (fow*foodWid)+20;
  fy = (c.height - 50)/ foodHei;
  foh = Math.floor(Math.random() * fy);
  foodY = (foh*foodHei)+20;
  ctx.fillStyle = foodColor;
  ctx.fillRect(foodX - foodWid, foodY - foodHei, foodWid, foodHei);
}

//move rectangle inside the canvas using arrow kesnakeYs
function snakeMovement(x){
  if(x == 'right'){
    snakeX = snakeX+20;
  }
  if(x == 'left'){
    snakeX = snakeX-20;
  }
  if(x == 'up'){
    snakeY = snakeY-20;
  }
  if(x == 'down'){
    snakeY = snakeY+20;
  }
}

var movementInterval;
window.onkeydown = function(event) {
        previousSnakeX = snakeX;
    previousSnakeY = snakeY;
    var keyPr = event.keyCode; //Key code of key pressed
    if(keyPr === 39 && snakeX<=460){ 
      movementInterval = setInterval(snakeMovement('right'), snakeSpeed);
    }
    else if(keyPr === 37 && snakeX>10){
        movementInterval = setInterval(snakeMovement('left'), snakeSpeed);
    }
    else if(keyPr === 38 && snakeY>10) {
        movementInterval = setInterval(snakeMovement('up'), snakeSpeed);
    }
    else if(keyPr === 40 && snakeY<=270){
        movementInterval = setInterval(snakeMovement('down'), snakeSpeed);
    }
    //clears anything below the snake
     ctx.clearRect(previousSnakeX, previousSnakeY, snakeWid, snakeHei);
    if(snakeX == (foodX - 20) && snakeY == (foodY - 20)){
    food();
    //Scoring stuff:
    ctx.clearRect(10,310,130,60);
    ctx.font = "30px Arial";
    score = score + 1;
    ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
    ctx.fillText('Score: ' + score, 10, 340);
  }
    //Drawing rectangle at new position
    drawSnake(snakeX,snakeY,snakeWid,snakeHei);
};
```

I am still relatively new to javascript, and definitely to intervals, so I am kind of confused on how to proceed. I thought what I have would work, but it does not work in the way I want it to. Any help would be much appreciated! This image is how it looks right now:
[image: This is what it looks like:]

Comment: try keeping your snake as an array of points that you can increment on the fly (like when you eat something) with the head always being at the current position. Note that every time you move the snake, you will need to update all of the array positions, probably in a forEach or similar.

Comment: The link is to and answer that addresses moving and growing a snake with example using an Array as a queue https://stackoverflow.com/a/40564577/3877726